# JTextArea Real Time Spell Checker

Tags: java, swing, spell-checking, jtextarea

I need a good spell checker library for Java that can spell check a JTextArea (or any JTextComponent) in real time.  That is, it should have a wavy red underline appear under text while the user is typing.

It needs to be able to list all the available word replacements by left clicking (yes, left clicking) the word.  If not possible, right-click is fine.

It needs to have an "Ignore All," but not an Add, Ignore, or any of the others.  Just Ignore All.

Ideally, you should be able to change how the dropdown box looks, at least to some extent.

No user-spell checker is needed.  That is, I don't need a button that when you click it brings up a spell check dialog, I *only* need real time checking.  I actually already have a spell checking dialog library.

If someone can suggest a good library (I am willing to pay for it) or, better yet, explain a good method for doing this to a textarea in the first place that would be fantastic.

At the very least if someone could explain how to check the JTextArea against my dictionary and put the red underline and the dropdown on clicking or any of these steps that would be a great start.

Thanks for the potential help.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523699/how-do-i-add-spell-checking-to-a-jtextarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with [Wintertree](http://www.wintertree-software.com/dev/ssce/javasdk.html)

Answer (score 3):

http://jortho.sourceforge.net/

Sample can be seen here
http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jortho/sample

Comment: I looked at this one.  Seems like a good one, but I found another similar one that is even better.  I still want something that's better yet (i.e. exactly what I need and free) but great suggestion.  I'm concerned about JOrtho's extensibility, i.e. can I change to use left click, dropdown style (no language, just the words) and ignore all?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make a complete list. Feel free to add.

### Full-blown solutions

- [JOrtho](http://jortho.sourceforge.net/)

  - Wordlist comes from Wiktionary
- [JaSpell](http://jaspell.sourceforge.net/) is a Java implementation of the popular Aspell.
- [JMySpell](https://kenai.com/projects/jmyspell)

  - Uses the OpenOffice.org dictionaries
- [Wintertree](http://www.wintertree-software.com/dev/ssce/javasdk.html)

  - non-free

### Libraries

- [HunspellJNA](http://dren.dk/hunspell.html) used as backend by LanguageTool
- [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/)
- [JSpell SDK](http://www.jspell.com/) can be used as basis
- [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) also includes a Grammar check

  - a small wrapper application is shown at https://github.com/pminos/languagetool-wrapper-demo-parent
- [Suggester](http://www.softcorporation.com/products/spellcheck/)

Comment: Good tutorial on how to use Jazzy:  http://moderntone.blogspot.com/2013/02/tutorial-on-jazzy-spell-checker.html